# How are routes getting set on RockyLinux 8 VM?

Tags: centos, networkmanager

I've got a RockyLinux 8-based VM which is correctly picking up the static routes set on its network (an OpenStack subnet with host_routes set). I don't understand how though.

Here's the routes:

```
[cloud-user@login-0 ~]$ ip r
default via 10.29.107.254 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 10.29.107.20 metric 100 
10.1.112.0/24 via 10.29.107.254 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 10.29.107.20 metric 100 
10.29.0.0/16 via 10.29.107.254 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 10.29.107.20 metric 100 
10.29.107.0/24 dev ens5 proto kernel scope link src 10.29.107.20 metric 100 
169.254.169.254 via 10.29.107.6 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 10.29.107.20 metric 100
```

And here's some output from `nmcli` for the active connection:

```
[root@login-0 cloud-user]# nmcli c show "System ens5" | grep -i route
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.routes:                            --
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 10.29.107.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.169.254/32, nh = 10.29.107.6, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 10.1.112.0/24, nh = 10.29.107.254, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = 10.29.0.0/16, nh = 10.29.107.254, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[5]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 10.29.107.254, mt = 100
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 169.254.169.254/32 10.29.107.6 10.1.112.0/24 10.29.107.254 10.29.0.0/16 10.29.107.254 0.0.0.0/0 10.29.107.254
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       routers = 10.29.107.254
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
```

The RedHat NetworkManager docs [show setting routes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/configuring-static-routes_configuring-and-managing-networking#how-to-use-the-nmcli-command-to-configure-a-static-route_configuring-static-routes) via `nmcli connection modify $connection_name ipv4.routes`, yet that entry is empty above. So how are routes being picked up here?

The reason I'm asking despite it working is it would help me debug a similar host which is not getting static routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(It would be helpful to see the full output of `nmcli -p -o con show -id "System ens5"`).

The answer is here:

```
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 169.254.169.254/32 10.29.107.6 10.1.112.0/24 10.29.107.254 10.29.0.0/16 10.29.107.254 0.0.0.0/0 10.29.107.254
```

`nmcli` outputs properties in upper case when they are set dynamically e.g., as opposed to statically defined as settings on the connection.

`DHCP4.OPTION` is an array that shows the DHCP options that were requested in NetworkManager's `DHCPREQUEST`, and received in the response from the DHCP server.

In this case, the first line tells us that a request was made for [classless static routes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3442).

The second line tells us that the DHCP server responded with those routes.

As a result, NetworkMangager duly added those routes to the routing table. It set `proto dhcp` on them [as a hint](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/%7Ecks/space/blog/linux/IpRouteProtoWhat) that they came from DHCP. This is only advisory, but usually it's a fairly decent place to start looking.

Comment: Please see https://pastebin.com/PsPYHAWp

Comment: Oh - that's odd, that *does* show various `IPV4.ROUTE` entries.

Comment: Better to put the output inline - pastebins aren't forever, Stack Exchange questions & answers should be! :)

Comment: `IPV4.ROUTE` lines were omitted because `grep` is case-sensitive. `grep -i route` would have shown them.

Comment: Duh, I'll edit the original

Comment: Cool. I think the presence of `rfc3442_classless_static_routes ` in `DHCP4.OPTION` tells you that the routes come from the DHCP server. I've edited the answer.